# Cocoapods install error

Tags: cocoapods

im trying to install cocoapods in a project oy mine, but i get always an error

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.35.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:103: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/pathname.rb:422:in `open': No such file or directory - /Users/CravenJM/.cocoapods/repos (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/pathname.rb:422:in `foreach'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/pathname.rb:422:in `children'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.35.0/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:63:in `all'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.35.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:130:in `repo_information'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.35.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:34:in `report'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.35.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:58:in `report_error'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.7.0/lib/claide/command.rb:300:in `handle_exception'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.7.0/lib/claide/command.rb:274:in `rescue in run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.7.0/lib/claide/command.rb:264:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.35.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:45:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.35.0/bin/pod:43:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

any idea what it could be or how i could fix that? i need cocoapods for an app, but its a nightmare :-)

Comment: Looks like the profile CravenJM was created for the sole reason to ask this question...

Answer (score 224):

I had the same error on a new Mac because I forgot to run "pod setup" after installing cocoapods. Because of that the specs repo was missing and the "pod install" command failed.

Comment: "Forgot" is maybe not right, as the CocoaPods guide doesn't really tell you to do it at all.

Comment: @Siten run "sudo rm -fr ~/.cocoapods/repos/master", and then pod setup again, finally pod install

Comment: I tried few time but after 3-4 times i got succeed. BYW Thanks @libra

Comment: You'd think there would be a fix in their instructions by now.

Comment: @Kim thank you so much.  I've been caught by this twice, now... apparently they are planning a release "extremely soon" that is expected to address this.

Comment: Accept this answer, for God's sake!

Comment: The account hasn't been used since asking this question, so this is probably never going to be accepted.